# The template for this display is not available

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I have a template for joomla, I intall the template and everything is fine but when I select this template and I see the page, I have this messages

The template for this display is not available. Please contact a Site administrator.

Any idea!!!

thanks

Hi everyone, thanks for the comments, but I have the same error... I saw  other template in joomla and I see that my template don´t have a index.php only index.html and css file and javascript file.

I change a htaccess.html file... like this

I include DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

and change the extension this htaccess.html like this .htaccess

But I still have the same error.

Any idea!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have had this happen to me several times, and in all cases it was a problem with the template installation, or missing files.  My fallback has always been to decompress the original files into the installed folder, or do a template installation on my laptop and FTP that template folder to the server.  Always turns out to have been a missing file/folder in the template installation.

Comment: This also happens when you use a `configuration.php` file from an older version of Joomla in a new version. I got this error when I used a Joomla 2.5 configuration file in a 3.1 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are passing any parameter in url or post method with name 'template'.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me to move by mistake a file (index.php) from /template into /template/images.
Sometimes using Cyberduck it happen and you don't realise.

```
The template for this display is not available. Please contact a Site administrator.
```

I identified the file and place it back and everything worked fine.

Hope it helps